# Windows Ce 6.0 Testing environment?

Tags: windows-ce

We are developing **Stand alone application** in .net compact framework 2.0 targeting windows ce 6.0 operating system.

But don't have any windows Ce 6.0 testing environment.

**Can any one give details how to setup Windows Ce 6.0 Testing environment?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsembedded/ce/dd402108.aspx